# How can I regenerate the default '/etc/' config files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, apt, aptitude

I've removed `nagios3` with `apt-get remove nagios3` and then removed the files in by using the command `sudo rm -R /etc/nagios*`

Now when I run `apt-get install nagios3` the config files (`/etc/nagios3/*`) are not present. How can I regenerate them?

This box is on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: "removed the files in by using"? I think there is a missing word here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purge `nagios3`. Then reinstall. That will probably work.

```
apt-get purge nagios3
apt-get install nagios3
```

The purge will get rid of the config files, which the system didn't delete initially, and so thought were still installed. If purging `nagios3` is not an option, then it will be a little more complicated. If that is the case, leave a comment.

Comment: cool. that helped. also had to do `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` and `sudo apt-get purge nagios-plugins-basic`